# Fast CPU v Lots of cores.... which is best?

Tags: central-processing-unit, xeon

We run an ecommerce platform with many sites and lots of crons continually running etc...

- Resources (images, js) are primarily delivered via CDN.
- Our server runs CPU intensive apps such as CXS Watch for WHM, clamd, R1Soft etc.

We're upgrading our server and we're deciding between:

- E3-1240v6 / 32GB ram
- E5-2620v4 / 64GB ram

My question, is this: what will give us the best result in terms of overall server performance and user experience?  SSD will be used which is a huge gain.

** we plan on launching a SAAS product in the next 12 months, and so want to cater for that too.

I will value your input, thank you.

Comment: You really need to benchmark your application to understand this. It sounds like you have a single server, which will be a single point of failure. How about two smaller servers, in different locations, with a cloud based load balancer (CloudFlare / CloudFront may be suitable). Cloud based computers are easy to scale up / out to provide redundency, but come at a cost that can be significantly higher than owning a server - though if you take into account staff, hosting, data center, etc, cloud can come out about the same.

Comment: cost is a factor and this kind of setup is prohibitive right now.

Comment: So you'll bet your business on not having a catastrophic hardware failure? Over a few thousand dollars?

Comment: Ridiculous comment.  Of course we have contingency plans. We backup using R1Soft as well as a separate off site 3rd party daily rsync that include multiple data rotation points.

Comment: In the end, we went with faster CPU, based on info from https://haydenjames.io/php-performance-additional-cpu-cores-vs-faster-cpu-cores/ which answered the question better then the linked answer above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is you would be better running more CPU cores. As you are running a lot of processes and your customers must be served in parallel, impacting each other less as possible, more cores is better over higher speed processors.